# Mean install fails

Tags: npm, mean-stack

ME$ mean init app

? What would you name your mean app? app

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:579
    throw e;
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.exports.checkNpmPermission (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/utils.js:70:3)
    at Array.checkPermissions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/install.js:36:11)
    at handleItem (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/async-series/index.js:14:13)
    at series (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/async-series/index.js:30:3)
    at Object.exports.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/install.js:14:3)
    at exports.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/cli.js:836:11)
    at PromptUI.completed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/wizard.js:43:5)
    at PromptUI.onCompletion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:69:10)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.completed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:1977:12)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onCompleted (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:1914:14)

ME$

I do not know how to troubleshoot this.

---

Further Details

OS:Yosemite
prerequisite Install:$ npm install -g mean-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are having some permission issues with the "npm".Did you install the mean using "npm install -g mean-cli" ?.

Comment: I needed to go back and fulfill the needed dependencies using npm install dependency -v 'xx.xx.xx' . Also receiving support helped. Thanks!